# Creating custom window function

Tags: postgresql

I have table of teams participating in events.

```
id,
event_id,
gender enum('men', 'mixed', 'women'),
age enum('ultraveteran', 'superveteran', 'veteran', 'open', 'junior'),
score
```

For every team I am trying to get a rank in each of age categories (note that superveteran category also contains ultraveterans, veterans contain both previous categories and open contains all categories).

I can get the rank for veterans with following query:

```
select id, (case age in ('ultraveteran', 'superveteran', 'veteran') then
      row_number() over (partition by event_id, gender, age in ('ultraveteran', 'superveteran', 'veteran')
      order by score desc)
   else null end) as rank_v
```

It isn't very nice as you can see. Because I have five categories the whole query starts to look quite messy (and I have another five similar "columns" for number of teams in each category).

I thought I would create window function to simplify it a bit but when I defined my window function (there isn't almost any documentation on this btw) I couldn't even get it to return argument passed to it.

```
select class_rank('veteran', 'open') over (partition by event_id, gender) as one
from team where event_id in (11,19);


create or replace function class_rank(ranked_class text, team_class text)
returns text as $$
 select ranked_class;
$$
language 'sql' window;
```

I thought maybe postgre doesn't support sql window functions as

> This is currently only useful for functions written in C

was stated in the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createfunction.html) (section Parameters → WINDOW) but it didn't throw any error and only returned null so I tried `select 'foo'::text` and this one worked so I assume you can define SQL window functions as well.

How can I create the function so that it accepts arguments properly?

P.S.: I know this would be much more efficient when written in C but the results are cached so it doesn't matter that much.

Answer (score 3):

Custom windows aggregates in SQL, PL/pgSQL are not really supported. Currently, there is no way to do this.

For more information look to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790028/how-to-create-a-custom-windowing-function-for-postgresql-running-average-examp).

Comment: Oh, the pl/v8 looks like it is working and I can use javascript now. Still it is weird creating sql window function doesn't throw any error and even works when I select static text.

Comment: @JanTojnar I looked there - it is a minor bug - you cannot to create a useful window function there. If you can, please report it as bug to http://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-bugs/

Comment: Is this still true? I see some documentation about a [moving-aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/xaggr.html#XAGGR-MOVING-AGGREGATES) mode that's related to using an aggregate function with a window query.

Comment: maybe it is not valid - lot of changes was there for last six years.