# Is there a way to reference a calculated value from the previous row and use that in the next row's calculation?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example, I have the following query and table:

```
SELECT generate_series * 5 as num
FROM generate_series(1, 5)

+-----+
| val |
+-----+
|   5 |
|  10 |
|  15 |
|  20 |
|  25 |
+-----+
```

I want to take the previous row's val however and continously multiply it by 5 such that I end up with the table:

```
+-----+
| val |
+-----+
|    5|
|   25|
|  125|
|  625|
| 3125|
+-----+
```

I know I could just go `5 ^ row_number` but the problem I need to solve requires that I craft the query to be able to reference the previous row's calculated `val`

Comment: The source table is a daily quote of stock prices

Comment: Use `5 ^ n`, then use the query as a subquery and use `lag` in the outer query to access the calculated value from the previous row.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out that I needed a custom aggregate function to call from this thread: [How to create a custom windowing function for PostgreSQL? (Running Average Example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790028/how-to-create-a-custom-windowing-function-for-postgresql-running-average-examp)

End result is this. It takes 2 decimal values, the first one being the one to multiply against while the second one serves as a default.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prod(decimal, decimal, decimal) RETURNS decimal 
LANGUAGE SQL AS $$
    SELECT ROUND(COALESCE($1 * $2, $3), 2);
$$;

DO $$ BEGIN
    CREATE AGGREGATE prods ( decimal, decimal ) (
      SFUNC = prod,
      STYPE = decimal
      -- INITCOND = 1.0
    );
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN duplicate_function THEN NULL;
END $$;
```

Called via:

```
prods(val, 5) OVER (ORDER BY val)
```

Answer (score 0):

use lag window function, supposing that lag is your ordering column

```
select val, val*coalesce(Lag(val,1) OVER ( ORDER BY val),1) as product from tbl
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @zip! However I need to calculate the row's `product` based on the previous row's `product` without referring to the previous row's val

Comment: Hi @Lorenzo, I am cconfused, you said "I want to take the previous row's val however and continously multiply it by 5 such that I end up with the table:" but on the comment you are saying you don't want to reference the previous row's val.

Comment: That's my fault, sorry! I worded it wrong. I think a better way to explain my problem would be to calculate the row's product using the previous row's product. Something like

`SELECT COALESECE(LAG(product, 1) OVER (ORDER BY val) * 5, 1) as product`

The issue here being that I can't reference product within itself

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little lost on why a custom aggregation function is needed.  This is a simple arithmetic progression.  Why not just do this?

```
SELECT gs.*,
       power(5, gs.x)
FROM generate_series(1, 5) gs(x);
```

Or if you really want to keep your original data:

```
SELECT gs.x * 5,
       power(5, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ts.x))
FROM generate_series(1, 5) gs(x);
```

Comment: To simplify the question, I used that table but I can see I could have "simplified" it better. The issue with my real data is that I need to be able to do this as I'll be multiplying the previous row's value with a different value on the current row.

Comment: @LorenzoAng . . . I would suggest that you ask a new, better question.  There is not a need for a customer aggregation function, I don't think.

Comment: My apologies. I worded my question wrong however it doesn't change the fact that I need a custom aggregation function. I'll keep it in mind and be clearer next time.